# XMLQUERY() WITHIN XMLATTRIBUTES()

Tags: db2, sqlxml

I am doing some basic tasks using, `sql/xml`. I am currently working on an error message that I get when trying to compute a `XMLQUERY()` within a `XMLATTRIBUTES()` function. (See code below)

```
SELECT XMLELEMENT(NAME "Nodename",
       XMLATTRIBUTES(XMLQUERY('$t//Element/text()' PASSING Info AS "t") AS "hello"))
FROM Kurs
```

The error message that I get, says that there is no qualified routine that can run the function. I cant copy-paste the error message because its in Swedish, but this should be enough.

Also this might help: SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884, DRIVER=4.18.60

So my question is (I have been looking for the answer), why doesn't this work? I will always get a value from that `XMLQUERY`, and it should simply translate into a value and used by `XMLATTRIBUTES()`

Any documentation, or link, is welcomed as well!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Good point! I am running IBM's DB2

Comment: To convert one XML document (fragment) to another you should probably use [XSLTRANSFORM](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0050650.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scalar function [XMLQUERY](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0022193.html) returns an XML value. The function [XMLATTRIBUTES](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0022184.html) expects an expression that returns a value of any type, but XML and some other types.

Thus, the functions are not compatible the way you are using them. DB2 cannot find a routine with that function signature. It results in that [error -440](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql00440n.html).

How about wrapping a CAST/XMLCAST around it...?